# How to trigger another app from React Native Webview? UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME error

Tags: react-native

From the React Native WebView to be able to open the related platform of Deep Link Scheme.

For example:

When the website I am viewing is trying to trigger another app.

```
 <WebView
          style={styles.container}
          originWhitelist={['*']}
          bounces={false}
          allowFileAccess={true}
          domStorageEnabled={true}
          javaScriptEnabled={true}
          geolocationEnabled={true}
          allowFileAccessFromFileURLS={true}
          allowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs={true}
          onNavigationStateChange={onNavigationStateChange}
          source={{
            uri:
              'http://onelink.to/6vdhky',
          }}
        />
```

https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview/issues/750
https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/pull/1136

[image ref one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EywJ9.png)

[image ref two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JMovQ.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried Linking.sendIntent() and Editing shouldOverrideUrlLoading() function in RNCWebViewManager.java but didn’t make it work. I finally ended up with https://github.com/lucasferreira/react-native-send-intent#readme
Here’s my code like:

```
  onShouldStartLoadWithRequest={(request) => {
          const { url } = request;
          if (
            url.startsWith('intent://') &&
            url.includes('scheme=kbzpay') &&
            Platform.OS === 'android'
          ) {
            SendIntentAndroid.openChromeIntent(url);
            return false;
          }

          return false;
        }}
```

Answer (score -1):

VAT/BTW number (optional)
Plus3dhedset
VAT/BTW number must be in NL123456789B12 format.
https://domains.google.com/registrar?favorites=0e70b499-a0f1-4bc6-850a-793c6f8392c7